# How to wire a Hammond 290EEX for France?

Tags: power

I asked the company directly how to wire the Hammond 290EEX to match the voltage here in France. The answer they gave was "the transformer has a universal primary and can be wired for many different mains", The data sheet does not show a 220 V primary tap, it does have multiple primary taps of 100, 120, 110 and 120 V. Is it possible to wire this by combining several primaries to match the line voltage? Or are they just blowing smoke you know where! Or is it just the incorrect power transformer for my 1965 Fender Bassman even though they claim it is a direct drop in for the original?
The original part number is 125P7D/022814 which they are showing in their chart as a direct replacement my amplifier. But the data sheet doesn't show the 220 V taps. Can anyone clear this up for me? Here is the data sheet- [image]

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VcrbQJiXA3E

Answer (score 3):

> *But the data sheet doesn't show the 220 V taps.*

and

> *Is it possible to wire this by combining several primaries to match
> the line voltage?*

Yes it is; a 100 volt winding on one primary in series with a 120 volt winding on the other primary.

[image]

> *Or is it just the incorrect power transformer for my 1965 Fender
> Bassman even though they claim it is a direct drop in for the
> original?*

I have no idea whether it's correct for your amplifier but, if you have a 220 volt supply, that's how you'd wire it.

> *The original part number is 125P7D/022814 which they are showing in
> their chart as a direct replacement my Amp.*

Hammond are a reputable supplier so I'd be tempted to believe they have this right.

Comment: Almost correct - voltage in france should be 230V AC 50Hz, the same as almost everywhere else in europe. I strongly recommend agains messing with mains voltage, you are risking yourself and others..

Comment: @TurboJ your comment should be aimed at the OP and not my answer. The OP asked for a 220 volt connection and that's what I provided him/her. In other words I answered the OP as to what he wanted and, any incorrectness is in the question and that's where you should lay the comment.

Comment: @TurboJ you might also want to take note of this: https://www.twothirtyvolts.org.uk/pdfs/site-info/Explanation_230Volts.pdf --> your observation is incorrect. The EU standard is 230 volts +10% and -6% and this fudges over the cracks of systems being incompatible. France still uses 220 volts and Britain still uses 240 volts but, in 1994 we called both systems 230 volts for convenience only. I've measured 245 volts in my house for instance.

Comment: Thank you very very much... you guys are the greatest.!!!!

Comment: @surfrat [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)